# How to check if the field is available in the form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I create `text` elements dynamically and it is not mandatory that all the fields available in the form but how do i check whether field is available using `javascript`, i tried the following.

```
if (!document.forms[0].dynamicField1 === undefined) {
                   alert("dynamicField1");
            }
```

if i try the above code i get the following exception ,

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'type': object is null or undefined
```

thanks

Comment: And what does these fields look like ?

Comment: Are you sure that code is causing that error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for typeof, that returns undefined if it does not exist

```
if (typeof document.forms[0].dynamicField1 === "undefined") {
   alert("dynamicField1");
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtorrescr/PvrC4/

There is something important and it is that you need to have the `<form>` tag present to allow this validation to work. If you have not `<form>` script will fail.